# Is there a way to run constrained EM?

Tags: expectation-maximization, constraint

I would like to run an EM (expectation maximization) algorithm to estimate hidden Markov model parameters except, in my case, I have an extra constraint on my start and final states in my HMM.

How do people generally do this? And how would this affect the Baum Welch updates and EM convergence guarantees?

Comment: My idea was to restrict the elements in my final state transition matrix and initial state vector so I have extra terms in my Lagrangian when maximizing log likelihood.